# Converting a numerical string to the equivalent multipled by 100

Tags: java, strings

Method:

- Input: a string which represents an integer or a non-integer value.
- Output: a string which represents the same value multiplied by 100.

Requirements:

- No floating-point unless needed.
- No leading 0s in the part left of the floating-point.
- No trailing 0s in the part right of the floating-point.

I cannot use the `Double.parseDouble` method, because it sometimes yields an "ugly" result.

For example:

```
String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("0.0071")*100)); // yields 0.7100000000000001
String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("0.072" )*100)); // yields 7.199999999999999
```

Here is my code, and I would like to know if there are any cavities in it:

```
String MultiplyBy100(String number)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String[] parts = number.split("\\.");
    if (parts.length == 1)
        sb.append(parts[0]+"00");
    else if (parts[1].length() == 1)
        sb.append(parts[0]+parts[1]+"0");
    else if (parts[1].length() == 2)
        sb.append(parts[0]+parts[1]);
    else
        sb.append(parts[0]+parts[1].substring(0,2)+"."+parts[1].substring(2));

    if (sb.charAt(0) == '-')
    {
        while (sb.length() > 2 && sb.charAt(1) == '0' && sb.charAt(2) != '.')
            sb.deleteCharAt(1);
    }
    else
    {
        while (sb.length() > 1 && sb.charAt(0) == '0' && sb.charAt(1) != '.')
            sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: @palacsint already answered this, but in a nutshell the issue is simply that floating point data types are imprecise and math operations on floats produce rounding errors at the edge of the precision of the data type (turning 0.0071 into 0.007100000000000001 for instance). That is *totally fine* as long as the error falls outside the precision you require. Decimal data types (scaled integers) on the other hand are not subject to those rounding errors. Math results from decimal types will be as precise as the inputs. **Caveat: decimal operations are extremely slow compared to floats**.

Comment: Also, my comment that "Math results from decimal types will be as precise as the inputs" was on the simplistic side, but these comment fields are short. The results will be as precise as the least precise of the inputs, and still not always perfect mathematically, and quite slow because the operations are 100% software with no help from specialized hardware. The decimal data type is fundamentally the same thing whether you're dealing with Java, C#, C++, MySQL or SQL Server. [This post is informative](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20482699/618649)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. It would be much easier with [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)s:

   ```
   String input = "00007.880000";
   BigDecimal hundred = BigDecimal.valueOf(100);
   BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(input).multiply(hundred).stripTrailingZeros();

   System.out.println(result.toString()); // prints "788"
   ```

   It works with big numbers well:

   ```
   String input = "0000123456789123456789.123456789123456789123456789123456789880000";
   BigDecimal hundred = BigDecimal.valueOf(100);
   BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal(input).multiply(hundred).stripTrailingZeros();

   // prints "12345678912345678912.345678912345678912345678912345678988"
   System.out.println(result.toString());
   ```

   Two readings:

   - *Effective Java, 2nd Edition, Item 48: Avoid float and double if exact answers are required*
   - [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3730019/843804)
2. The original code returns `788.0000` for `00007.880000` which I guess does not fulfill the specification.
3. Java developers usually start method names with lowercase letters.

   > Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

   Source: [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language, 9 - Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Comment: So much for the answer I was half way through

Comment: What about 1.234? Will `BigDecimal` yield 123.4?

Comment: @barakmanos you should read the documentation and try this. It will help you learn. But, yes, it will.

Comment: Oh... was probably thinking of `BigInteger`...

Comment: And this does not have the same problem as with `Double.parseDouble`?

Comment: @barakmanos: It handles those cases properly. (Answer updated.)

Comment: Thanks. Regarding your second comment: I assume that the input is already "aligned" with the requirements of the output, so `00007.880000` is not a viable input in my program (though, I should have probably mentioned that in the question). Regarding your third comment: I know, it's just a typo (happened when I copied the code I wanted to be reviewed into a separate method). Thanks again for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 6):

Aside from palacsint's great suggestions:

- You are using a StringBuilder, yet you still are doing string concatenations.
- Your code for removing the leading zeros duplicates the <s>`for`</s> `while` loop.

Also: Why is your original input a string? This doesn't feel right. I've got the feeling there is something wrong with the bigger picture of your code.

EDIT: I meant the `while` loops. Better would be something like:

```
int startAt = sb.charAt(0) == '-' ? 1 : 0;

while (sb.length() > startAt + 1 && sb.charAt(startAt) == '0' && sb.charAt(startAt + 1) != '.')
   sb.deleteCharAt(startAt);
```

EDIT 2: Better readable?

```
boolean negative = sb.charAt(0) == '-';
if (negative) sb.deleteCharAt(0);

while (sb.length() > 1 && sb.charAt(0) == '0' && sb.charAt(1) != '.')
  sb.deleteCharAt(0);

if (negative) sb.insert(0, '-');
```

(Add brackets to taste)